# Not install genymotion plug in for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, genymotion

I want to add genymotion plug in for eclipse,i read guide in Home page Genymotion and I click help in toolbar eclipse,i click install new software -> add.Then I type http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse in textbox location.I wait but my eclipse not show plug in genymotion.I try add jar file but it also not run.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the plugin

You can install Genymotion plugin for Eclipse in one of the following ways:

```
Update Site method (recommended);
Manual method.
```

Update Site method (recommended)

```
Start Eclipse.
Go to Help/Install New Software menu and click Add.
Fill in the fields with the following values and click OK.
    Name: Genymotion
    Location: http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse
Expand Genymobile.
Click Select all and Next.
Click Next.
Read and accept the license terms.
Click Finish.
A security warning indicates that the plugin is not signed; click OK.
Click Yes to restart Eclipse.
```

The Genymotion plugin button  is displayed

Manual method

```
Ensure Eclipse is closed.
Download the plugin from the Genymotion download page.
Follow the steps corresponding to your operating system:
    Windows
    If you have administrator rights, put the .jararchive in the Pluginsdirectory of the Eclipse installation folder.
    Without administrator rights, put the .jararchive in the Pluginsdirectory of the Local Settings\Eclipse folder.
    Mac OS X
    With administrator rights, put the .jararchive in the Plugins directory of the Eclipse installation folder.
    Linux
    If you have administrator rights, put the .jararchive in the Plugins directory of the Eclipse installation folder.
    Without administrator rights, put the .jararchive in the Plugins directory of the /home/<user>/Eclipse folder.
```

Comment: I add http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse to location,but it not show genymotion